# Warning: returning reference to local temporary object

Tags: c++, clang

Compiling the following:

```
namespace platform {
  struct event {};
  struct keyboard_event : public event {};

  const platform::event& wait_event()
  {
    return platform::keyboard_event(); 
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  const platform::event& event = platform::wait_event();
  return 0;
}
```

Yields the following warning with clang

```
main.cc:7:12: warning: returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return platform::keyboard_event(); 
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which makes sense but the new wording in C++11 seems to imply that returning a const reference to a value extends it's lifetime until the reference goes out of scope?

The current draft isn't loading for me so I'll cite cppreference.com instead:

> The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see reference initialization for details.

Comment: `platform::keyboard_event()` is r-value. You bind it with `const&` and return it. But you can't return reference to temp, const or not. It's classic "returning reference to temporary" warning.

Comment: if you follow the link in "see reference initialization for details", cppreference continues on to say "a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "returning a reference" does not magically extend any lifetime.

The only time that lifetime is extended is when a prvalue (or an xvalue referring to a member of a prvalue) is bound to a reference *variable*, and the lifetime of the prvalue is extended to that of the variable:

```
struct Foo{};

{
    const auto & r = Foo{};   // Foo object not destroyed at semicolon...
    // ...
}
// ... but is destroyed only here.
```

Your prvalue is not bound to any variable, and hence no lifetime is extended.

(Also note that non-static class data members don't count as "variables" for this consideration, so you also can't extend lifetimes via constructor initializer lists if your class happens to have reference members.)

Comment: Okay so chalk that it worked up to undefined behaviour / luck that the stack did not change. So extending the lifetime by const l-value or r-value references cannot be used to return by reference in any scenario?

Comment: @CasperBeyer no, only return by value - which would be fine in this case

Comment: returning by value in this case would cause slicing, no? (assuming there's different data sets per struct)

Comment: @CasperBeyer: You need to rethink your design. Maybe you can return a reference to an existing global object (since your trait classes seem to be empty anyway). Or maybe use something completely different.

Comment: There are more extension scenarios than just prvalue initializing reference variable; e.g. xvalue initializing reference variable where the xvalue is a subobject of a temporary

Comment: @M.M: Yes, good point. Any more cases other than that example?

Comment: @KerrekSB If I were to do:                               
`return std::move(some_temp_constructed_obj)` will that work if my return type is an rvalue ref? If yes why? thanks

Comment: @MosheRabaev: it will compile, but it won't extend any lifetimes. Only lifetimes of _prvalues_ are extended when those are bound to references; your proposal deals only with glvalues.

Comment: @KerrekSB So it will compile but the behavior is undefined is that what you are saying?